# DLL load failed with scipy.optimize?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I'm trying to upload the curve_fit from scipy.optimize to fit an exponential function to some data I have generated. My code looks like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
```

When I run the code, I get the following error:

> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

I have scipy in an Anaconda folder on my computer, and I'm 80% sure I installed it. How do I fix this error? (Or if you have a better way of fitting an exponential function to data, I'm all ears)

Thanks!

edit: Here is the full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\Casey\Documents\Python\Perc_MatPlot3.py", line 10
    from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
  File "C:\Users\Casey\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\__init__.py", line 146
    from .optimize import *
  File "C:\Users\Casey\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 35
    from .linesearch import (line_search_BFGS, line_search_wolfe1,
  File "C:\Users\Casey\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\linesearch.py", line 16
    from scipy.optimize import minpack2
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Either it isn't installed correctly, or scipy is not in your pythonpath, because that import should work. Can you import scipy at all, or is it just scipy.optimize?

Comment: Please post the _full_ error.  Are you sure you are running the correct version of python?  Have you tried reinstalling?  I have adjusted your tags because this is unrelated to matplotlib, but definitely a windows issue.

Comment: I had no problems with "import scipy" but my code as written produced the error

Answer (score 20):

I encountered the error

```
    from ._ufuncs import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

when using [cgoehlke's "Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages" for SciPy](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) with a pip3-installed NumPy, overlooking this note:

> Many binaries depend on NumPy-1.9+MKL and ...

Their [NumPy](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) provides the missing DLLs / modules.

Comment: Occurred importing scipy.special in one of my own libraries.  Works fine in Spyder, but when I try idle - ouch.  Please post more on how to install MKL.

Answer (score 4):

I've run into several problems like this recently when trying to use pyplot and scipy. I have Anaconda 2.7, 32bit running on Windows 7 x64

I just encountered this exact error whilst trying to use curve_fit. I downloaded the 'superpack' from sourceforge: http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/

Running this installer fixed the error and didn't affect any other part of my python environment.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is an answer for you, because this error can mean so many things... I've been there...

I just had the same error (also while loading Scipy optimize) just 10 minutes ago with a fresh install of Miniconda for Python 3.3 on a Vista x64 machine. Somehow it failed to add the main Python directory to the Windows PATH (and I'm pretty sure I didn't uncheck the box for it at the end of the installation).

I did the same procedure on some XP and Windows 7 machines earlier this week without any problems, so i caught me a bit by surprise.

If you have no other Python installation on your machine, you can check if running 'python' (type win-key + r, or do it from command prompt) works. If it doesn't, simply add your main installation directory (where python.exe is located) to your PATH variable.

If this doesn't work you could use `Dependency Walker` to check which DLL the error message is actually about, and then see if that DLL is present somewhere within your `PATH` or `PYTHONPATH`.

I have had the same `DLL error` when multiple versions of the same DLL were compiled with different compilers and the required version wasn't found first. If removing a version (the program it came with) isn't an option, changing the order of your PATH variable can help.

Answer (score 0):

I was suffering from exactly the same problem.

```
from scipy.optimize import minpack2
```

I reinstalled numpy and MLK but still got this error on Pycharm. I directly update my python to 3.6 and now the problem is solved.
During the procedure, use

```
conda install python=3.6
```

Since

```
conda update python
```

showed me that I already have the 3.5.2, which means conda update failed to update from 3.5 to 3.6 and it is supposed to be capable of upgrading from versions like 3.5.1-->3.5.2 I think.
Hope this could help. Plus, remember to reset the environment after the update.

Answer (score -2):

This is most likely you installed 32-bit Python but 64-bit libraries or vice versa.

You need to remove Python and reinstall correct python.

https://www.python.org/download/

Here you can download Python.

Remember you python libraries should be the same 32bit or 64bit as the one of Python.