# 'ImportError: DLL load failed' when fetching Iris dataset via sklearn

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I just updated my installed anaconda by `conda update --all`. Then I try to fetch the Iris dataset as follows:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
data = load_iris()
```

Then I get the error message: ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Here is my `conda info`

```
           platform : win-64
      conda version : 4.3.30
   conda is private : False
  conda-env version : 4.3.30
conda-build version : 3.0.27
     python version : 3.5.4.final.0
   requests version : 2.18.4
   root environment : C:\Users\Win10Home\Anaconda3  (writable)
default environment : C:\Users\Win10Home\Anaconda3
   envs directories : C:\Users\Win10Home\Anaconda3\envs
                      C:\Users\Win10Home\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
                      C:\Users\Win10Home\.conda\envs
      package cache : C:\Users\Win10Home\Anaconda3\pkgs
                      C:\Users\Win10Home\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/win-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/win-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/noarch
        config file : None
         netrc file : None
       offline mode : False
         user-agent : conda/4.3.30 requests/2.18.4 CPython/3.5.4 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.15063
      administrator : False
```

I have tried several solutions out there but all of them did not work well. 
I am using python 3.5.4, sklearn 0.19.1.

Ps. I also found the similar problem on stackoverflow 2 years ago. The python version in that problem is 2.7. There are no working solutions.

Comment: I try using `jupyter notebook` and it works. But not in Eclipse as I stated in my question.

Comment: Try installing numpy+mkl -  http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy
The problem could come from there as proposed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22753695/dll-load-failed-with-scipy-optimize

Comment: It does not work as well.